# how to print shapes in python? looking into a different and more efficient way

Tags: python, shapes

Have tried many ways, such as printing line by line:

print (" ------- ")

print ("|       |")
print ("|       |")

print (" ------- ")

Also with * ,

print ("********")

print ("*      *")
print ("*      *")

print ("********")

Personally, I think the dashes (-) look more smooth than the stars(*). Any other ways to do this?

Comment: What shape exactly are you trying to print?

Comment: And also, make sure to read the guide on proper question writing.

Comment: Why not use [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) instead (like [this](https://repl.it/repls/DeepLongBookmarks))? Or grab a library off PyPI that does it for you?

Comment: Why are you asking about "efficient" here? You can probably squeeze out a few nanoseconds by building one big string and printing that, instead of doing 4 separate `print`s, but I can't imagine when that would ever matter (especially since the actual displaying on the console or saving to a file will probably take something like 1000x as long as that anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which of these would you rather have:

```
┌────────┐
│        │
│        │
└────────┘

 --------
|        |
|        |
 --------
```

Unless you need to output pure ASCII for some reason—or you're going for that retro APPLE ][ look—you should draw boxes with [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character). And it's really not much harder than drawing them with hyphens and pipes and other things not meant to be used for line drawing:

```
horiz = '\u2500'
vert = '\u2502'
ul = '\u250c'
ur = '\u2510'
ll = '\u2514'
lr = '\u2518'

def box(width, height):
  top = ul + horiz*(width-2) + ur
  middle = vert + ' '*(width-2) + vert
  bottom = ll + horiz*(width-2) + lr
  lines = [top] + [middle]*(height-2) + [bottom]
  return '\n'.join(lines)

print(box(10, 4))
```

---

It's sometimes even easier to grab a library off PyPI that does what you want, like [`terminaltables`](https://pypi.org/project/terminaltables/) for drawing tables with borders, or [`asciitree`](https://pypi.org/project) for drawing trees like the DOS and Unix tree commands, etc.

---

Or, depending on what you're trying to do, maybe you actually wanted to write a [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) or [`urwid`](http://urwid.org/) or similar full-screen console app, and let it draw boxes around your windows.

Answer (score 0):

Guff way:

```
def box(w,h):
   s='┌%s┐'%('─'*w)
   for i in range(int(h/2)):
      s+='\n│%s│'%(' '*w)
   s+='\n└%s┘'%('─'*w)
   return s

print(box(5,5))
```

Comment: Why give a novice code golf when they're not asking for it?